# Is the following series consisting of $\pm 1$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems, random-walk, ergodic-theory

[(Link to cross-post to MathOverflow)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266913/)

> Let $b=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}2$ and $a_n:=(-1)^{[nb]}$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the floor function. Are the partial sums $A_N=\sum\limits_{n=0}^N a_n$ bounded?

The sequence $nb\bmod 2$ is equidistributed in $[0,2]$, so, as $n$ gets large, there will be about half of indices in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ that correspond to $1$ and the other half to $-1$. This doesn't help much though because what it says is basically $A_N\in o(N)$.

By testing on computer softwares, it seems that $A_N\in O(\log N)$.

Also, is there anything special about $b$ besides being an irrational real number? What if one replaces it by, say, $\pi$?

Comment: Random walks are not bounded, so there's a good chance your series isn't either.

Comment: @TMM yes I will certainly agree. But is there an obvious way to kind of connect the two? The problem is that there is simply no randomness in my series (also I don't see how we can regard it as the expectation or other (deterministic) numerical characteristics of the random walk either)

Comment: The real question thus comes down to: what can you say about the sequence in the exponent. Maybe it is somehow possible to rewrite the individual terms in terms of the binary expansion of b?

Comment: @TMM that would be an onerous task if we have to deal with *each* $bn\mod 2$ explicitly. Somehow I still think we should instead deal with the "global" distribution, e.g. the asymptotic behaviour of the ratio $$\dfrac{\#\{i\mid bi\mod 2\in [0,1], i\le n \}}{n}$$

Comment: These ratios converge to $\frac12$, which does not tell much about your series $\sum a_n$ except what you already know, namely, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^Na_n=o(N)$.

Comment: @Did I'm still not clear about whether it is bounded or not. In hopes it is, I would expect the ratios to behave like $1/2+O(1/n)$.

Comment: This seems somewhat related to the 2x mod 1 map, except that here x(n+1) = x(n) + b instead of x(n+1) = 2*x(n). Maybe it's worth searching if any similar series results are known for the 2x mod 1 map? And you would easily be able to show it is bounded if you just proved b is rational ;-)

Comment: You really should be patient with MSE and do not post to MO so quickly.

Comment: The sequence $\{[nb]\}$ is called a *Beatty sequence*, which might help you search for relevant results.

Comment: This has already asked and answered [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266913/is-the-following-series-consisting-of-equally-distributed-pm-1-bounded). It is enough to invoke the Denjoy-Koksma inequality. Closing the thread.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-site duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266913/is-the-following-series-consisting-of-equally-distributed-pm-1-bounded.